# What does 'sanding a doorstep' mean?

Tags: meaning, verbs, literary-english, charles-dickens

What does "sanding a doorstep" mean?

Does it mean polishing the doorstep?  Or filling it in with sand?

I read this expression in Charles Dickens' book, *The Haunted House* where it says,

> I found the landlord of the little inn sanding his doorstep.

Comment: Since it is a *doorstep* (close to your veranda/terrace), *polishing* might be the correct one, I think. People usually don't pour sands on their doorsteps, they sprinkle them. Besides, the *little inn* in your updated question indicates that there are things "decorating" the doorstep.

Comment: How do you fill a doorstep with sand? And to what end?

Comment: There is no further info on that. But I guess you are right, polishing it is.

Comment: It *could* be sprinkling sand on the step to make it less slippery, but people did use blocks of sandstone for polishing (like navy holystone).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means the landlord of the little inn was scouring his doorstep, probably with sand and water as it is described as 'sanding'.

*[Stone floors and stone stairs are sometimes scrubbed with sand and water](http://www.oldandinteresting.com/scrubbing-stones-sand.aspx), sometimes with the hearth-stone, or with pipe-clay prepared after the following receipt: Boil half a pint of size [glue] with the same quantity of whiting and pipe-clay in two quarts of water; the stones must be first washed clean with water, and this mixture afterward laid smoothly on them with a flannel; when dry, they must be rubbed with a dry cloth or flannel. Stone floored kitchens and offices, stone hearths, stone steps, and balconies are usually washed with a flannel and water, and, while wet, scrubbed with the hearth-stone. Steps at the entrances of houses are washed and whitened every day in town, in the country scarcely more than once a week; stone kitchens twice a week, balconies only once.*
Webster's Encyclopedia of Domestic Economy, New York 1845 and later editions

Comment: Surely OP will have his own copy, like all the rest of us?

Comment: I am not sure they have a Farsi edition.

Comment: The modern-day equivalent would be of the proprietor removing bubble-gum stains on the pavement before the store, early on a Sunday morning. It speaks to the energy and attention to detail that can enable a man to earn a comfortable life from even the most mundane of occupations.

Answer (score 3):

The reference to doorstep sanding that I located is a slightly more simple method than that given by Roaring Fish, but from 75 years earlier.

In [**Madam Johnson's Present: Or Every Young Woman's Companion, In Useful And Universal Knowledge**](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yTpdAAAAcAAJ&dq=madam%20johnsons%20present&pg=PA162#v=onepage&q=Sand&f=false) (1770) by Mary Johnson, page 162, she deals with how a maid should go about cleaning various parts of the house, including the following brief description:

> Cold Water, Soap, and Sand, will do for washing Free-stone Slabs; and she should use a Brush for cleaning them; for rubbing with a Fire-stone spoils the Ladies Petticoats, and one cannot set a Foot on Slabs, so rubbed, without marking the Room, unless the Slabs be afterwards well cleaned with a dry Cloth.

The concept appears not to have died out entirely, as in [**The Cambridge Social History of Britain, 1750-1950**](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1x-OEg8f1ykC&lpg=PA436&dq=%22sand%20the%20doorstep%22&pg=PA436#v=onepage&q=%22sand%20the%20doorstep%22&f=false) (1990) By F. M. L. Thompson, Page 436, is found the following paragraph, depicting a typical Southern perspective of Northern England:

> The caricature is of a dirty, grimy industrial region full of pits and blast-furnaces where the men wear caps, drink beer out of straight glasses, grow leeks and race whippets while the women stay at home, wear 'pinnies' and curlers and **sand the doorstep**.

Answer (score 1):

In Yorkshire the thresholds were regularly scoured with holystone, a type of sandstone.  It was common to see housewives on their knees with a pail of water and a rectangular or square holystone vigorously rubbing clean the Yorkshire stone doorways, steps and flags.  They also edged the steps in a different colour.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please note that this site expects answers to be "as an expert would write them". This means that references should eb used to back up assertions. I assume you are implying that using a holystone is called "sanding"; if so this is missing from your answer as well as unsupported by references. If you're not saying that, then you're not answering the question.